# Dynamic writeFormula in openxlsx is overunning past last row of my data frame in excel output

Tags: r, excel, automation, openxlsx

I am using openxlsx::writeFormula to create a workbook that will be dynamic to whatever data is being pulled into it.

```
ROWCNT <- row(tab_1)+1
MONTHLY <- "'Monthly'!"
TAB1 <- "'Tab_1_Data'!"

writeFormula(WB, sheet = 'Tab_1_Data', glue('SUMIFS({MONTHLY}$G:$G,{MONTHLY}$A:$A,{TAB1}B{ROWCNT},{MONTHLY}$B:$B,{TAB1}A{ROWCNT})'),
             startRow = 2, startCol = 3)
```

The above code is producing the desired values in the cells that have a corresponding row. The problem I am stuck on is that after the last row, the cells that are dependent on writeFormula are repeating from the start well past the last row. Right now I have to clean this out of the data in Excel after the fact, is there a reason this is continuing past the last row and a way to stop at the last value of row(tab_1)?

tab_1 is a data frame with 264 rows an the first column in Excel is the column names of tab_1.

Comment: `row(tab_1) + 1` returns a matrix with as many rows as rows has tab_1 dataframe (let us call it nr)  and columns as columns has tab_1 (nc).  If I understood well, first column in Excel has the column names of tab1, that is nc. Therfore, you will always fill nr*nc rows with the `writeFormula` instead of the expected nc. May be you wanted to write `(1:dim(tab_1)[2]) + 1` that is an enumerator from 2 to number of columns plus 1, instead of `row(tab_1) + 1`.

Comment: Indeed, it was giving nr x nc rows, pulling in the first values from the matrix `1:dim(tab_1)[1] + 1` appears to have done the trick as I am only creating a column with 264 values in the formulas. Thanks!